# How to convert html table of element to Arraylist element in Robot framework

Tags: python, arraylist, robotframework

I have tried to get an element of HTML table value and tried to split it to ArrayList element (rows) an Example:

- I need to get Text of @{xpath_location}[2]
- I need to Click Element of @{xpath_location}[5]

[image]

I used to Get Webelements and the result is:

```
@{Row5} = [ <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="15a5573d-6584-4669-bbce-1b4bf61f3298", element="f175bac9-2f59-4e8b-a24b-2e098aea47a7")> ]

List variable '@{Row5}' has no item in index 2.
```

I get element by "Get table cell" and then I can get a string of the value but I can not select the checkbox in this table (6th column).

Answer (score 0):

finally, I know how to select the checkbox by Set Variable of the xpath:

```
Validate Data4Click
     [Arguments]     ${row}
     ${CPid}=    Get Table Cell    ${AddN_C.value_table}     ${row}  3
     AddnoteChxboxColumn    ${row}
     [Return]    ${CPid}

AddnoteChxboxColumn
     [Arguments]     ${row}
     ${xpathAddnote_column}=   Set Variable  xpath=/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[6]/input[4]
     Validate chkbox has selected    ${xpathAddnote_column}

Validate chkbox has selected
     [Arguments]     ${locate}
     Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${locate}    ${timeout}
     Checkbox Should Not Be Selected     ${locate}
     Select checkbox   ${locate}
     Checkbox Should Be Selected     ${locate}
```